# Finding option within select options fails in Chrome and works in IE.. why?

Tags: jquery, select, google-chrome

I have a select list with multiple items which I want to be able to filter by the text entered into some text field.  This is pretty simple if you just do a js contains while iterating over each option.  There are however in some cases a lot of options, so I employed jQuery:

```
var results = $("#myList options").find("option[text*=" + someVal.toUpperCase() + "]");
```

This works fine in IE, but not in Chrome and I simply cannot find out why (Firebug doesn't work at all on this page, but that's an aside.

Perhaps it's because "text" doesn't actually exist in the option html, but no searching by value fails too.  Any ideas?

Comment: How many #myList elements are there in the page?

Comment: $("#myList options") looks for all `options` (note the trailing "s") elements under the element with ID "myList". Unless I've missed something important, there is no HTML element named `options`.

Comment: are you putting `text` as an attribute??

Comment: Ah that's what you get for not pasting the exact script you are using.  Actually I have a var which holds the equivalent of $("#myList")[0].options.

The code to find options by text value does work in IE.  I simply find it odd that it doesn't work in Chrome and that I can't seem to find a way to get it to work in Chrome.

Comment: An interesting question and one which I am embarrassed to answer truthfully.  About 13,000..........  yes.. I am going to trash the approach and use some kind of paging this which retrieves the data ajaxly.  I just really wanna know why this approach doesnt work! I managed to get teh 13k records rendering very quickly, storing them and in IE even filtering them pretty quickly.. odd

Comment: it doesn't work because `#myList options` will match nothing. Use `option` instead. `option[text*=` will possibly not match in every browser. Check for `option[value*=` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use jQuerys [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead.

```
var results = $("#myList").children('option').filter(function(){ 
    return ( $(this).val().indexOf(someVal.toUpperCase()) > -1 );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

there are many errors here...

```
var results = $("#myList options").find("option[text*=" + someVal.toUpperCase() + "]");
 //                         ^              ^
```

the above code, will get all `options`' (option with an `s`). then look for children option containing a text attribute with `someVal.toUpperCase()` value.......

I guess you would want like this,

```
var results = $("#myList option").map(function(){
                  if ($(this).text().indexOf(someVal)!= -1 ) { return this; }
              }).get();
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried with the following on chrome:
http://jsbin.com/olida3/edit

correctly alerts "1" for 'test'

```
$('#myList option[value*='+val+']');
```

Alternatively you could also write it like

```
$('option[value*='+val+']', '#myList');
```